# Google Cloud Backend Bucket Quota Exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

We are currently migrating our infrastructure from AWS to GCP and I am in charge of migrating our static websites from one place to the other.

What I used to do in AWS to publish a website is the following:

1. Create an S3 storage and upload the static files to it.
2. Create an entry on Cloudfront to use the Amazon CDN and use HTTPS traffic.
3. Add a CNAME on my DNS pointing to the Cloudfront DNS, so my users would access something like: site.mydomain.com.

Now that I am in GCP I did the following:

1. Created a bucket and uploaded all the static files to it.
2. Created a load balancer.
3. In the load balancer backend options, I created a backend bucket from my regular bucket and checked the CDN option.
4. In the frontend options, I added an endpoint (with a static IP) and the HTTPS option.
5. Added an A record on my DNS so that my users would continue to access the site.mydomain.com.

The problem is that Google is telling me that I reached the limit of backend buckets that I can create (apparently this is 9, at least for me).

So I guess that I must be doing something wrong here... What would be the best practice to host static websites from the Google Cloud?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas "Not all projects have the same quotas. As your use of Google Cloud Platform expands over time, your quotas may increase accordingly. If you expect a notable upcoming increase in usage, you can proactively request quota adjustments from the Quotas page in the GCP Console."

Comment: Indeed I asked for more quotas and they gave me. Thanks for the tip!